# Swift firebase query nested child nodes

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following set up in firebase:
[image]

I then query the firebase:

```
func getUserInfo(){

var tempUsers = [user]()
           // query for the data 
        let itemRef = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "[url]").child("users")
        itemRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

            for child in snapshot.children {

        if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
            let dict = childSnapshot.value as? [String: Any], 
            let sport = dict["Sport"] as? String, 
            let username = dict["username"] as? String{

                let user = user(sport: sport, username: username)

                tempUsers.append(user)
            }
         }
             self.usersArray = tempUsers                           

        }){ (error) in
            print("the error is: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
  }
```

Users:

```
    class user {

            var username: String 
            var sport: String
            var teamInfo: [teamInfo]


      init(username: String, sport: String, teamInfo: [teamInfo])
  {
    self.username = username
    self.sport = sport
    self.teamInfo = [teamInfo]

  }
}

struct teamInfo {
  var AwayTeam: String
  var HomeTeam = String
  var Jersey = Int

}
```

I would like to know how would I be able to get the Team information within my query and then be able to add it to the instance of User, I have tried to make "Team" into a dict but this does not give me the intended result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: you have an inconsistency in `username`. Your JSON spells it `Username` with an uppercase `U`, while the code uses `username` with a lowercase `u`. Since Firebase is case-sensitive, your code will right now never get the correct value.

Aside from that, you can get the values from the nested children by using [`DataSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath:)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#childsnapshotforpath).

```
itemRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children {

    if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
        let dict = childSnapshot.value as? [String: Any], 
        let team = childSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Team/AwayTeam").value as? String;
```

Comment: would there be a way without including "Team/AwayTeam" as it is possible not every use has an AwayTeam there for it might not be in the data

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there, but mostly included `Team/AwayTeam` as an example. If it doesn't exist, `team` will be `nil`. And you can read the other properties in a similar way, e.g. `Team/HomeTeam`.